# How can I generate code from file at compile time using a macro?

Tags: crystal-lang

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
CountryCode,CountryName
AD,Andorra
AE,United Arab Emirates
AF,Afghanistan
AG,Antigua and Barbuda
// -- snip -- //
```

and a class that looks like this:

```
module OpenData
  class Country
    def initialize(@code : String, @name : String)
    end
  end
end
```

and I want to have a class variable within the module automatically loaded at compile time like this:

```
module OpenData
  @@countries : Array(Country) = {{ run "./sources/country_codes.cr" }}
end
```

I tried to use the "run" macro above with the following code:

```
require "csv"
require "./country"

content = File.read "#{__DIR__}/country-codes.csv"
result = [] of OpenData::Country
CSV.new(content, headers: true).each do |row|
  result.push OpenData::Country.new(row["CountryCode"], row["CountryName"])
end
result
```

but this results in

```sh
@@countries : Array(Country) = {{ run "./sources/country_codes.cr" }}
                                    ^
Error: class variable '@@countries' of OpenData must be Array(OpenData::Country), not Nil
```

All my other attempts somehow failed due to various reasons, like not being able to call `.new` within a macro or stuff like that. This is something I regularly do in Elixir and other languages that support macros and is something I would suspect Crystal can also achieve... I'd also take any other way that accomplishes the task at compile time!

Basically there are several more files I want to process this way, and they`re longer/more complex... thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Found the issue. It seems that I have to return a string that includes actual crystal code from the "run" macro. So, the code in the "run" file becomes:

```
require "csv"

content = File.read "#{__DIR__}/country-codes.csv"
lines = [] of String
CSV.new(content, headers: true).each do |row|
  lines << "Country.new(\"#{row["CountryCode"]}\", \"#{row["CountryName"]}\")"
end

puts "[#{lines.join(", ")}]"
```

and everything works!

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question here in SO :)

Answer (score 3):

You already found your answer, but for completeness, here are the docs, from: https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.2.2/Crystal/Macros.html#run%28filename%2C%2Aargs%29%3AMacroId-instance-method

> Compiles and execute a Crystal program and returns its output
> as a `MacroId`.
>
> The file denoted by *filename* must be a valid Crystal program.
> This macro invocation passes *args* to the program as regular
> program arguments. The program must output a valid Crystal expression.
> This output is the result of this macro invocation, as a `MacroId`.
>
> The `run` macro is useful when the subset of available macro methods
> are not enough for your purposes and you need something more powerful.
> With `run` you can read files at compile time, connect to the internet
> or to a database.
>
> A simple example:
>
> ```
> # read.cr
> puts File.read(ARGV[0])
> ```
>
> ```
> # main.cr
> macro read_file_at_compile_time(filename)
>   {{ run("./read", filename).stringify }}
> end
>
> puts read_file_at_compile_time("some_file.txt")
> ```
>
> The above generates a program that will have the contents of `some_file.txt`.
> The file, however, is read at compile time and will not be needed at runtime.